# failed to call save hook while attempting to use the "save hook" functionality in Bosun

Tags: bosun

> failed to call save hook: fork/exec hook/hook.go: exec format error. Restoring config: successful

[image]

Comment: Show your attempt or at least post steps to reproduce your issue

Comment: Not positive, but sounds like maybe there is something wrong with the command you have Bosun configured to call when there is a save (maybe wrong architecture, or lacking executable permission).

Comment: Oh, or if you pointed `CommandHookPath` to a file that is not a compiled program, but rather a .Go file containing go code (which is not a executable), you might see an error like that.